# Thumbnail and Conditional Links for 2 loops within single.php

Tags: php, thumbnails, conditional-statements, wordpress

Here's my issue. I want all thumbnails to link to the post
EXCEPT for the main loop thumbnail in single.php to link to an external website
BUT ALSO for the second loop "related post thumbnails" in single.php to link to post

"Code A" below only accomplishes the first 2 goals.
How can I make second loop in single.php "Related Posts Thumbnails" to link to the post (instead of an external website)?

I am using:

```
the_post_thumbnail('large') for main loop in single.php
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') for second loop in single.php
the_post_thumbnail('medium') for everything else
```

.
"Code A": All thumbnails link to post except thumbnails in single.php links to external website

```
function my_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) { 
if ( is_single() ) { 
    $name = get_post_meta($post_id, 'externalurl', true);
    if( $name ) {           
        $html = '<a href="'.$name.'" title="' . esc_attr( get_the_title( $post_id ) ) . '">' . $html . '</a>';
    }
    return $html;
}
else 
{
    $html = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_the_title( $post_id ) ) . '">' . $html . '</a>';
    return $html;
}
}

add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_image_html', 10, 3 );
```

.

"Code B": Second loop in single.php "Related Posts Thumbnails"

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'orderby' => rand
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>

<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile;?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

On second pass, your code works fine on my system. The permalinks are correct. There is, however, an extra ")" in your second loop:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') ); ?>
```

Try removing it and see if things improve.

Edit:

Adding a fourth parameter:

```
function my_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id, $size ) { 
    if ( $size == 'large' ) {
        echo 'large';
    }
}

add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_image_html', 10, 4 );
```

Also, in your second lop, change your requested size from thumbnail to large:

```
 <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
```

Comment: No change when removing the extra ")". Currently the code links thumbnails in both the main AND second loop (within single.php) to an external website. Is there any way to make the second loop link to posts? Or alternatively, is there a way to do a conditional statement for the_post_thumbnail('large') to link to external website while other thumbnail sizes link to the post?

Comment: You can check the requested size by adding a fourth parameter to your filter, check edit.